# Python redmine api: journals.filter usage

Tags: python, python-redmine

For example I have an issue:

```
issue = redmine.issue.get(100)
```

It is possible to get the notes of particular user for this issue?

I found journals.filter method:

```
issue.journals.filter()
```

But I don't know syntax for filter() method.

Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance.

BR, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine API doesn't allow you to do that via direct API calls, so you have to first include journals (otherwise you'll make 2 API calls instead of one) and then iterate over them and check if that record belongs to the needed user, e.g.:

```
issue = redmine.issue.get(ISSUE_ID, include='journals')

for record in issue.journals:
    if record.user.id == USER_ID:
        print record.id, record.created_at
        print record.notes
        print record.details
```

Comment: Hello Max. Thank you for answer! It's exactly what I need.